# Mapbox Geolocation, how to load into map?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, geocoding, mapbox

I have being playing around with MapBox and I am having some issues with getting the GeoLocation API to send data back to the map and update the it.

This is what I got right now:

```
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'TOKEN-HERE';
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
         container: 'map', // container id
         style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', 
         center: [-0.968539, 54.562917],
         zoom: 9 
  });

  map.on('style.load', function() {
      map.addSource("myMap", {
             "type": "geojson",
             "data": "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/UK_ADDRESS_HERE.json?country=gb&types=address&autocomplete=true&access_token=TOEKN"
      });

      map.addLayer({
          'id': 'test1',
          'type': 'line',
          'source': 'myMap',
          'interactive': true
      });
 });
```

Comment: and what errors are you receiving in your JS console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer may lie with how you are encoding `UK_ADDRESS_HERE`.

> https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/UK_ADDRESS_HERE.json

---

The [request format for the Mapbox Geocding API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/?language=cURL#request-format) requires that *since the {query} parameter can contain any value, it should be URL-encoded*.

That means that a simple geocode request like `10 Downing Street, Westminster` must be encoded using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to `10%20Downing%20Street%2C%20Westminster`.

Try this and verify that your request is proper.

```
curl https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/10%20Downing%20Street%2C%20London.json?access_token=${MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

Comment: Please can you help with this,   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945104/using-mapbox-for-geolocation-in-html