# Using MapBox for Geolocation in html

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I would like to display the address on dynamics CRM using MapBox API, i
have used Google API and it works perfectly, but now i would like to display it using map box.

I have looked at the forward geo-location feature of Mapbox but it's not yet clear.
So my variable my address variable will be coming from a field.
e.g var address = "6 Antares Drive, Ottawa, Ontario K2E 8A2, Canada";

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Add a geocoder</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.43.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.43.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css' type='text/css' />
<div id='map'></div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibGF3aXgxMCIsImEiOiJjamJlOGE1bmcyZ2V5MzNtcmlyaWRzcDZlIn0.ZRQ73zzVxwcADIPvsqB6mg';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-79.4512, 43.6568],
    zoom: 13
});

var address = "6 Antares Drive, Ottawa, Ontario K2E 8A2, Canada";

var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({ accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken });
geocoder.query(address); // how do i search and display this address
map.addControl(geocoder);

//map.addControl(new MapboxGeocoder({
 //   accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
//}));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can the address be displayed similar to that of google map on the Html Page.

Comment: See details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330100/mapbox-geolocation-how-to-load-into-map/38335288?noredirect=1#comment82860905_38335288   when encoding the URI component yields  `curl https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/6%20Antares%20Drive%2C%20Ottawa%2C%20Ontario%20K2E%208A2%2CCanada.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibGF3aXgxMCIsImEiOiJjamJlOGE1bmcyZ2V5MzNtcmlyaWRzcDZlIn0.ZRQ73zzVxwcADIPvsqB6mg`

Comment: Thanks , but please it did not work for me.

Comment: Thanks, but please it did not work. I have revised the html                                                                      
  var test = "6 Anatares Drive, Ottawa , ON , K2E 6AE, Canada";
var address = encodeURI(test);
var dataz= "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/"+address+".json?"+"autocomplete=true&access_token=TOEKN""
// After the map style has loaded on the page, add a source layer and default
// styling for a single point.
map.on('load', function() {
    map.addSource('single-point', {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": dataz
    });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Console.Log was very helpful, I found out that the data.features.center returns the coordinates which was all what i needed . the full code is below

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.43.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.43.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #map {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body style="word-wrap:break-word;">
  <div id='map'></div>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/mapbox@1.0.0-beta9/dist/mapbox-sdk.min.js'></script>

  <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibGF3aXgxMCIsImEiOiJjamJlOGE1bmcyZ2V5MzNtcmlyaWRzcDZlIn0.ZRQ73zzVxwcADIPvsqB6mg';
    console.log(mapboxgl.accessToken);
    var client = new MapboxClient(mapboxgl.accessToken);
    console.log(client);

    var address = 't5h 0k7'
    var test = client.geocodeForward(address, function(err, data, res) {
      // data is the geocoding result as parsed JSON
      // res is the http response, including: status, headers and entity properties

      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.url);
      console.log(data);

      var coordinates = data.features[0].center;

      var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
        center: coordinates,
        zoom: 14
      });
      new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(coordinates)
        .addTo(map);


    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

[mapbox-gl-geocoder](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder) is a geocoder **control** for Mapbox GL JS, it's intended to provide a the user interface, that is, an input search box for searching on top of the Mapbox Geocoding API.

If you already have your query and just want to display that location on the map you're better to use the [Mapbox JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js) with `geocodeForward`, see https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js#installation.

Comment: Thanks Andrew you are right, but I do not understand how to use the SDK since its just a stand alone webresource on dynamics crm. so what i Just need is an html page that can do the query and display the result something like this function https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/point-from-geocoder-result/  only without the search

Comment: Yeah if you look at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js#installation there is an example of using it via the script tag so you can use it on a standalone htms page.

Comment: Thanks , I can see the initialization, but I do no see the display. Also for the address do i have to encode using encodeURI() function , becuase its a long address containing post code, city, province and county ..instead of 'Chester NJ'.....but where is the address displayed with a marker.'

Comment: The mapbox-sdk-js handles URL encoding. Once you get the results back you can add it to your map as a symbol using a GeoJSON source or an HTML Marker. The Mapbox GL JS docs have examples for both of these.

Comment: The mapbox-sdk-js handles URL encoding. Once you get the results back you can add it to your map as a symbol using a GeoJSON source or an HTML Marker. The Mapbox GL JS docs have examples for both of these.

Comment: when i checked the log using console.log i saw a url parameter on the result.   https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/6%20Antares%20Drive%2C%20Ottawa%2C%20Ontario%2C%20K2E%206AE%2C%20Canada.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibGF3aXgxMCIsImEiOiJjamJlOGE1bmcyZ2V5MzNtcmlyaWRzcDZlIn0.ZRQ73zzVxwcADIPvsqB6mg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066274/display-location-with-mapbox-java-script-sdk/48066459#48066459

Comment: Also this method cant be used globally :  client.geocodeForward(address, function(err, data, res) {
});  the parameters like err data or res cannot be used outside the block, also if i try to initialize a map like map = new mapboxgl.Map , the method is not recognized

Comment: thanks @AndrewHarvey finally figured it the console.log was very helpful, i found out that the data.features.center returns the coordinates which in turn i used on the map   var coordinates = data.features[0].center;