# Display Location with MapBox java-script SDK

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox, geocoding

How do I display location of an address on an HTML page using MapBox SDk forward Geo-Coding function.
The SDK already does the query, but I need to be able to display the map and its location with a point on the html.
here is my sample code.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MapBox</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.43.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.43.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="word-wrap: break-word;">
<script src='https://unpkg.com/mapbox@1.0.0-beta9/dist/mapbox-sdk.min.js'></script>
<script> 
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibGF3aXgxMCIsImEiOiJjamJlOGE1bmcyZ2V5MzNtcmlyaWRzcDZlIn0.ZRQ73zzVxwcADIPvsqB6mg';
console.log(mapboxgl.accessToken);

var client = new MapboxClient(mapboxgl.accessToken);
console.log(client);

var address = '6 Antares Drive, Ottawa, Ontario, K2E 6AE, Canada'
var test= client.geocodeForward(address, function(err, data, res) {
  // data is the geocoding result as parsed JSON
  // res is the http response, including: status, headers and entity properties
  
  console.log(res);
  console.log(res.url);
  console.log(data);
  console.log(err);

  });
  
console.log(test);





// how do I display the address on the HTML?





</script>
</body>

</html>
```

console.log(res.url) gives me the desired url but how do I display the map and add a marker to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `<div>` tag that will hold your map. See [here for an example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/simple-map/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Display a map</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.43.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.43.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div> // this is the line you're looking for
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibGF3aXgxMCIsImEiOiJjamJlOGE1bmcyZ2V5MzNtcmlyaWRzcDZlIn0.ZRQ73zzVxwcADIPvsqB6mg';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // id of the div you assigned above
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', // stylesheet of basemap you want
    center: [-74.50, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I know about this, but I need a an address queried not lng and latitude..I found out the  that the mapbox-gl-geocoder it's intended to provide a the user interface, that is, an input search box for searching on top of the Mapbox Geocoding API.

If you already have your query and just want to display that location on the map you're better to use the Mapbox JavaScript SDK with geocodeForward.

Comment: Ahh I see. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks am trying to display the maps on microsoft dynamics crm. So the address is always fixed and not meant to be interactive

Comment: thanks I finally figured it.